# Using Previously Calculated Values To Calculate another Variable

Tags: r, loops, vector

So I am new to R and to stackexchange/overflow, but here it goes. So if I have a vector lets just say it looks like...

> x <- matrix(c(1,2,3))

and I want to calculate a variable "Y". "Y" has an initial value of 100, so I would want to calculate Y[2],Y[3] and so on using the formula Y[i]=(x+1)*(Y[i-1]) for i >= 2. This is something that can pretty easily be done in excel and I would like to know how the code looks in R. I have done calculations like this in MatLab with loops, but I have heard loops are the death of R, so I am trying to steer clear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the expected result, but maybe this:

```
x <- 1:3
n <- 5

Y <- 100 * outer(x + 1, 0:n, "^")
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]  [,5]   [,6]
#[1,]  100  200  400  800  1600   3200
#[2,]  100  300  900 2700  8100  24300
#[3,]  100  400 1600 6400 25600 102400
```

I've transformed your implicit formula to an explicit formula, i.e., Y[i] = Y[0] * (x + 1) ^ i. I use then `outer` to apply this to the `x` vector.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think the output I want is a single column vector. So this would not be the desired output. Also Y[i] = Y[0] * (x + 1) ^ i is not the formula that I put in, Y[i]=(x+1)*(Y[i-1]) is. Thank you for your help! I think that I can probably play around with the outer function to find how to solve it.

Comment: Well, show the expected output in your question. And my formula should give the same values as yours. That's basic maths.

Comment: Rereading my comment back it came out a little more aggressive than intended, nonetheless thank you.